# What renders a cytoplasm basophilic?

Tags: cell-biology, microscopy, histology, eukaryotic-cells

I know that being basophilic or acidophilic corresponds to affinity to certain dyes used in microscopy.

What i want to know is what characteristics of the cytoplasm can we infer from its basophilic property? Does it give us any idea about its different compartments relative abundance, or practical features of the cell? Can we predict how acidophilic and basophilic cells differ in their life and roles?

Thanks for help.